# Is there a way to buy airline tickets separately but still sit together?

Tags: tickets, airlines, children

I have a child that is with my ex at the moment and will be flying out to see me. I want to buy one of the tickets for my child and my ex wants to buy their own so they can get a round trip and head back after dropping my kid off with me. Is there a way to buy my child's one way ticket and my ex to buy their round trip ticket but them still sit together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, I do this all the time you have two ways of doing this, assuming your child needs it own seat (more than 2 years of age)

1. Speak to a travel agent, or the airline's reservation office.
2. Do it yourself online **but only at the website of the airline you are flying with** don't do this from a third party provider like expedia or similar.

You would first book the round trip fare, select your seats (you may have to pay for this), and then book the one way fare, and select the seat.

You just have to make sure the outbound flight is the same.

I have done this many times on Emirates and works without fail. You just have to be careful of the fare class, as not all will allow you seat selection at the time of booking. Some need you to pay, others will only allow seat selection 24 hours before departure - at which time it may be too late.

If all else fails, you can ask the check-in agent, the gate agent and the flight crew to help accommodate you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Check-in online  and select the seats so that you can sit together atleast one day in advance.

Last time we traveled, I did buy 2 tickets separately for me and my wife. I checked in online before the trip and i handpicked 2 seats so that we could sit together.

You may also ask at the airline counter but if the flight is full (most cases) you may be given a random allocated seat. Dont rely on this. We were refused close seats last time because the flight was full. Learnt a lesson.